# get mysql count of id in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, mysql, csv

I am trying to get count of column **user_Id** using `count(user_Id)` from **mysql** as follows:

```
 count=$(mysql -uroot -proot csv_imports -e "select count(user_Id) from test_data where user_Id=\"12345\";")
```

I am not getting what is wrong with it. I want it's **numeric** result. What could help me?

Comment: `count()` tells you how many records match your query - if your table `user_Id` only has one record where `user_Id=12345` count will only return `1`

Comment: I am ok with it. But currently nothing is happening. I at least want **numeric** result **1**

Comment: any another solution to find presence of **that** **user_Id**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command:

```
count=$(mysql -uroot -proot csv_imports -e "select count(user_Id) from test_data where user_Id=\"12345\";")
```

Will probably fetch something like:

```
+---------------+
| count(userid) |
+---------------+
|             5 |
+---------------+
```

Because that is the default output of a `mysql` query.

To suppress the header and column names, you should include the options `-s` (silent) and `-N` (skip column names)

That way, the `mysql` command only returns the `5` (based on my output) which will be stored in the variable using:

```
count=$(mysql -s -N -uroot -proot csv_imports -e "select count(user_Id) from test_data where user_Id=\"12345\";")
```

Try to write the value of your `count` variable in a terminal using:

```
echo "$count"
```

If it only returns a `5` (again, based on my output), you can use it as a numeric value in test expressions and calculations.